# echo-ing colored text in bash once uses the same color for all other echo's

Tags: bash, colors

I want one of my outputted lines in my bash script to be colored differently, so I used the following command:

```
echo -e "\e[38;5;11m Test"
```

This prints out `Test` in yellow text. After that, I run this:

```
echo "No changes made... exiting"
```

There is nothing that specifies color here, but it still prints out in yellow.

When you set the color of outputted text one time using `echo`, does it set the global text color for all other `echo`'s? If so does that mean I have to specify the text color every time I want to output text in order to override it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you guessed, whenever you set the color in the console, it persists until it is changed or reset. You can reset to the normal text color by using the following code:

```
\e[m
```

In other words:

```
# appears yellow
echo -e "\e[38;5;11m Test\e[m"

# appears normal
echo "No changes made... exiting"
```